# Inkscape distorts SVG, browser does not

Tags: inkscape, svg, distort

I have this image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Sphere_wireframe.svg.

When I download and open it in my browser (firefox and chromium) or image viewer (eog in my case), the graphic looks like this:

[image: Sphere correct]

When I open the image in Inkscape I get the following:

[image: Sphere distorted]

Longitude and latitude lines of the sphere appear to be interrupted and some are distorted or not reaching to the horizon of the sphere. The svg file doesn't seem to be too complex.

Do I need to transform the file in any way to be able to open it with Inkscape? I'm using Inkscape 0.91 r13725 on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate this problem using Inkscape 0.92 in Windows 10. It displays the exactly the same in Inkscape as it does in the browser. Perhaps you should update to a newer version?

Comment: Hi, thank you for testing and giving me the hint, I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Billy Kerr (see his comment above) I was able to solve the problem. I'm still not sure what the reason was but I did some research and found out that as of ver. 0.92 the [default resolution of Inkscape was changed](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Important_changes) from 90 dpi to 96 dpi. At least I notice this now when I open my older Inkscape svg files, that I have to make some adjustments in order to open these files.

To install the newest version of Inkscape (which is 0.92.5 at the moment) with Ubuntu 16.04 I had to add their stable-daily ppa repository and update the software like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

For anyone interested the libraries `libpotrace0`, `python-scour` and `python-uniconvertor` have by package dependency been installed in the process.

Thanks Billy for your quick response!

Comment: Hi.If this solution worked for you, please don't forget to choose your own answer as best!